# Problem with JS/JSX Code Auto-formatting Using Prettier in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, formatting, jsx, prettier

I am experiencing an issue with the auto-formatting of my JS/JSX code in VSCode. I'm using the **Prettier** extension.

I want to format the following code snippets:

```
  { id: 'e1', title: 'Toilet Paper', amount: 94.12, date: new Date(2020, 7, 14) },
```

or

```
 <ExpenseItem title={expenses[0].title} amount={expenses[0].amount} date={expenses[0].date}></ExpenseItem>
```

On saving, the formatting doesn't match my expectations. My goal is to have the code formatted as shown below:
{
id: 'e1',
title: 'Toilet Paper',
amount: 94.12,
date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),
}

and

```
<ExpenseItem
  title={expenses[0].title}
  amount={expenses[0].amount}
  date={expenses[0].date}
></ExpenseItem>
```

I've tried using the `Shift + Alt + F` keyboard shortcut, but even that does not resolve the issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have suggestions on how to rectify this formatting problem?

Thank you in advance for your help!